# nutch configuration to crawl entire website without specifying depth

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I am using Nutch-1.8 for crawling website and solr for indexing.i need to crawl entire website till the last child link without specifying depth parameter(-depth)

this is the command i am using to crawl and index urls

**command :** bin/crawl seeds brainiademo http://localhost:8983/solr/ 10

**syntax** : `bin/nutch crawl <urlDir> [-solr <solrURL>] [-dir d] [-threads n] [-depth i] [-topN N]`

in above command I don't want to specify depth parameter i.e., 10.

what are the configuration changes need to be done in order to crawl entire website without specifying depth parameter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set a value of -1 to the depth since Nutch 1.11. See [crawl script](https://github.com/apache/nutch/blob/trunk/src/bin/crawl#L180)

Comment: just set -1 instead of 10. Won't work with 1.8 as explained above

Comment: you mean i have to specify depth -1 in command itself? i tried it,it will inject seeds url to crawldb and crawling process will exit.i won't do any iterations

Comment: which version of Nutch are you using?

Comment: nutch-1.8 itself. is there any turnaround for 1.8?

Comment: Copy the modifications from the crawl script in 1.11 to the version you are using. BTW you could at least mark my answer as useful, couldn't you?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do that. But the work around is to configure nutch to crawl only links from the same domain, then put the crawling depth to very huge number (say 1 million). Nutch will keep crawling while there are links to crawl. Once there are no urls to crawl, it will stop regardless of the depth limit.